# Functions in Python (pygame)

Tags: python, image, function, pygame

Apologies in advance if this is a simple fix (I am relatively new to programming). I am creating a python game (with pygame) that will include a lot of images. I am currently using the following code to import and scale the pictures according to the screen resolution:

```
pygame.init()
WINDOW= pygame.display.Info() # size of window's width in pixels
WINDOWW = WINDOW.current_w
WINDOWH = WINDOW.current_h
size = 1920/WINDOWW

CreditsL = pygame.image.load ('TEXT\Credits.png')
Creditsrect= CreditsL.get_rect()
Credits = pygame.transform.scale(CreditsL, (int(Creditsrect.w/size), int(Creditsrect.h/size)))
```

Since I  have to import tons of images I would like to know how I can make a function that will import and scale the pictures, instead of me having to copy and paste.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be careful with `'TEXT\Credits.png'`. Backslash usually indicates an escape sequence. `'TEXT\Credits.png'` happens to work, but `'TEXT\title.png'` does not indicate the filename that you'd probably expect. To avoid this, use either forward slashes `'TEXT/Credits.png'` or raw strings `r'TEXT\Credits.png'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def resize(imgpath):
    img = pygame.image.load(imgpath)
    rect = img.get_rect()
    return pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(rect.w/size), int(rect.h/size)))


Credits = resize('TEXT\Credits.png')
```

If you want to avoid having to copy-paste this last line for each and every image, use a list of [(name, path),] tuples and build a dict from it:

```
SOURCES = [
    ("credit",  'TEXT\Credits.png'),
    ("something", 'TEXT\whatever.png'),
    # etc
    ]

IMAGES = dict((name, resize(path)) for name, path in SOURCES)
```

Then to use the resized "credit" image :

```
do_something_with(IMAGES["credit"])
```

Comment: Thannk you, just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to wrap your current code lines into a function and call it:

```
def importer(path):
    CreditsL = pygame.image.load(path)
    Creditsrect = CreditsL.get_rect()
    return pygame.transform.scale(CreditsL, 
                                  (int(Creditsrect.w/size), 
                                   int(Creditsrect.h/size)))

Credits = importer('TEXT\Credits.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaling the image through pygame, from my understandings, is not the way to go. Use a simple photo editor (Paint if you gotta!) to scale your image accordingly. It is more work for the computer to do. The more work your computer does, the less efficient the game! Memory might not be an issue now, but it would probably be wise to make good practice, as well as make your code easier to look at.